# How do I stop a file changing groups when it is edited

Tags: chown

My Debian LAMP web server has files in the website document root with owner:group set at [username]:www-data.

When I edit such a file by connecting using sftp and using a text editor the group changes to [username]:[username].

How can I prevent this?

Comment: [How does sftp replace files?](https://serverfault.com/a/637347) Compare [How does vim steal root owned files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58880/108618)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: use SetGID on the parent directory

```
chmod g+s /path/to/dir
```

then

```
chown -R [username]:www-data /path/to/dir
```